# VB.Net: Refreshing a combobox after adding /updating/deleting

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have two forms: **MainForm.vb** and **AddForm.vb**

**AddForm.vb** adds records to the database. 
**MainForm.vb** basically has the ***DataGridView***, ***Update***, and ***Delete*** functions.


In the MainForm.vb, I have a combobox.  The combobox stores the Full Names in the database.  Here's the code in the **Load** Function

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Lanz Buyao\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OffenseDatabase\OffenseDatabase\dbOffense.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

    Me.TblStudentTableAdapter3.Fill(Me.DbOffenseDataSet5.tblStudent)
    Me.TblOffenseTableAdapter3.Fill(Me.DbOffenseDataSet5.tblOffense)
    Me.TblGetsTableAdapter3.Fill(Me.DbOffenseDataSet5.tblGets)

    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Student_ID, FullName FROM tblStudent ORDER BY LastName", con)
    Dim tbl As New DataTable

    adp.Fill(tbl)

    adp.Dispose()
    con.Dispose()

    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Student_ID"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = tbl
```

It works as it should.  It properly displays the data to the combobox

Here is the event code for the combobox

```
Try
        con.Open()

        Dim CTR As Integer
        Dim das As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT (tblGets.Student_ID) As CTR FROM tblGets INNER JOIN tblStudent on tblStudent.Student_ID = tblGets.Student_ID where tblGets.Student_ID = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() & "' AND tblStudent.Section = '" & hiddentextbox.Text & "'", con)

        CTR = das.ExecuteScalar()
        das = Nothing

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter



        'display in table
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select tblGets.Student_ID, tblStudent.LastName, tblStudent.FirstName, tblStudent.MiddleName, tblStudent.Gender, tblStudent.ContactNumber, tblGets.OffenseCode, tblOffense.OffenseDesc,
                     tblOffense.OffenseCategory, tblGets.Date, tblStudent.Remarks, tblStudent.Guardian, tblStudent.Location, tblStudent.Address FROM tblStudent INNER JOIN
                     tblGets ON tblStudent.Student_ID = tblGets.Student_ID INNER JOIN
                     tblOffense ON tblGets.OffenseCode = tblOffense.OffenseCode WHERE (tblStudent.Student_ID = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() & "' AND tblStudent.Section = '" & hiddentextbox.Text & "')", con)

        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        con.Close()

        'display in textbox
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            editlastname.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("LastName").ToString()
            editfirstname.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FirstName").ToString()
            editmiddlename.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("MiddleName").ToString()
            editcontact.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ContactNumber").ToString()
            grdn.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Guardian").ToString()
            loc.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Location").ToString()
            address.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Address").ToString()

        Else
            hdlbl.Text = "changed"
            editlastname.Clear()
            editfirstname.Clear()
            editmiddlename.Clear()
            editcontact.Clear()
            grdn.Clear()
            loc.Clear()
            address.Text = ""

        End If

        If CTR = 0 Then
            STATUS.Text = "NONE"
        ElseIf CTR = 1 Then
            STATUS.Text = "WARNING"
        ElseIf CTR = 2 Then
            STATUS.Text = "CALL PARENT"
        ElseIf CTR = 3 Then
            STATUS.Text = "SUSPENSION"
        ElseIf CTR = 4 Then
            STATUS.Text = "SUSPENSION"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        con.Open()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT tblGets.Student_ID,tblStudent.LastName, tblStudent.FirstName, tblStudent.MiddleName, tblGets.OffenseCode,  tblOffense.OffenseDesc, tblOffense.OffenseCategory, tblGets.Date FROM tblGets INNER JOIN
                     tblOffense ON tblGets.OffenseCode = tblOffense.OffenseCode INNER JOIN
                     tblStudent ON tblGets.Student_ID = tblStudent.Student_ID WHERE tblStudent.Section = '" & hiddentextbox.Text & "' ORDER BY tblStudent.LastName", con)
        da.Fill(dt)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        con.Close()
    End If
```

This code does what it should.  It properly displays the contents of the item that I clicked on the DataGridView.

Now, here's the problem.

I have a **Refresh** button to test if everything is refreshing.  Apparently, none of the solutions I've tried works.

***Solution 1***
Calling the MainForm_Load function again.  Like so...`MainForm_Load(Nothing, Nothing)`  Doesn't really work because it conflicts with this.
`Me.TblStudentTableAdapter3.Fill(Me.DbOffenseDataSet5.tblStudent)
 Me.TblOffenseTableAdapter3.Fill(Me.DbOffenseDataSet5.tblOffense)
 Me.TblGetsTableAdapter3.Fill(Me.DbOffenseDataSet5.tblGets)`

***Solution 2***
First declaring the `ComboBox1.DataSource` to `Nothing` then refilling it with the same line of code that's used to bind in the MainForm_Load function.  It apparently conflicts with this `ComboBox1.ValueMember.ToString()` whenever I try to do that.

I've searched for some references online and they all say the same.  Some are so complex that it's not applicable for my codes.  I've been at this for five days and this is my only problem.

So, if anyone can help out, this would do some people who are struggling with the same problem a favor.

Comment: did you try simply add this after **con.Close()** `ComboBox1.Refresh()`

Comment: @Mederic doesn't work :(

Comment: What about creating a dynamic combobox something like: `With ComboBox1
            .ItemHeight = 32            .Top = 20
            combobox1.items.add(myitem)
        End With`